# Azure Notification Hub GCM registration

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement the Azure Notifications Hub tutorial, But I constantly receive the following error after registering with GCM-

```
05-16 12:23:13.041 V/MyBroadcastReceiver-GCM( 6848): GCM Registered: *REMOVED*
05-16 12:23:13.432 I/System.out( 6848): IntentService[null] calls detatch()

05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347): Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionString
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12083 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:444 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (System.IntPtr instance, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr constructorId, Android.Runtime.JValue* constructorParameters) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:412 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub..ctor (System.String p0, System.String p1, Android.Content.Context p2) [0x00106] in <121d9056830b46cdb962cb2ba28729a1>:0 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at AzurePushNotification.Plugin.PushHandlerService.OnRegistered (Android.Content.Context context, System.String registrationId) [0x00033] in D:\My Apps\AzurePushNotificationForXamarinForms\AzurePushNotification\AzurePushNotification.Plugin.Android\MyBroadcastReceiver.cs:81 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Gcm.Client.GcmServiceBase.handleRegistration (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x0006e] in <7579a4156fae4c4f9456441a941ea31e>:0 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Gcm.Client.GcmServiceBase.OnHandleIntent (Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x00021] in <7579a4156fae4c4f9456441a941ea31e>:0 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at Android.App.IntentService.n_OnHandleIntent_Landroid_content_Intent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_intent) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-25/src/generated/Android.App.IntentService.cs:119 
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:ca9fb80d-a955-4867-b512-0ebf0af2f472 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace ---
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionString
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.setConnectionString(NotificationHub.java:344)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.<init>(NotificationHub.java:114)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at md5214eafb7e7b3b7fcc363a68a6358563f.GcmServiceBase.n_onHandleIntent(Native Method)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at md5214eafb7e7b3b7fcc363a68a6358563f.GcmServiceBase.onHandleIntent(GcmServiceBase.java:44)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
05-16 12:04:35.521 I/MonoDroid( 4347):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I am Instanciating the NotificationHub as follows :

```
Hub = new NotificationHub(ApiKeys.AzureHubName, ApiKeys.AzureListenConneciton,
                                        context);
```

I am passing the context from my MainActivity, my Azure Listening Connection string is correct, as it does actually return a registration id for GCM.

Comment: @Medadec did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Kyle, unfortunately I did not, I implemented OneSignal instead, which has worked out.